# Ajax prototype to load page then update hash

Tags: ajax, hash, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I have 3 page with different concept/layout/animation.

I'm using prototype & script.aculo.us

I have this in my navigation:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#page1" id="page1" onClick="showPage(page1);">PAGE1</a></li>
<li><a href="#page2" id="page2" onClick="showPage('page2');">PAGE2</a></li>
</ul>
```

and this is in my js:

```
windows.location.hash: 'web';

function showPage() {
startloading();
var url: '/localhost/page2'+web;
new Ajax.Updater('maincontent', 'page2', { method: 'get' });
finishloading();
}
```

the question & problem is:

1. Why in windows location hash is still: /localhost/page1/#page2 with or without if I use var url?
2. All the animation in page 2 doesn't work, because I didn't put the header, but if put I it, I got double header and still the animation won't work either.

Can anybody give me the solution?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Shouldn't `windows.location.hash: 'web';` be `windows.location.hash= 'web';`?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to update your hash is:

```
window.location.hash = '#'+yourValue;
```

Hard to tell what exactly you're trying to do with your function but there's a few things that are clearly a bit wrong.

```
function showPage(var) { 
    startloading();
    var url: '/localhost/page'+var;
    new Ajax.Updater('maincontent', url, { method: 'get' });
    finishloading();
}
```

depending on what you're actually doing its fairly likely you would probably want something more like this:

```
function showPage(var) {         
    var url = '/localhost/page'+var;
    new Ajax.Updater('maincontent', url, { method: 'get' ,
        onCreate: function(){
            startloading();
        },
        onComplete: function(){
            finishloading();
        }
    });
}
```

Thats complete guesswork though, if you can provide more detail i can help more.

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
var url: '/localhost/page2'+web;
```

line throws error so hash cannot be changed. Fix it to

```
var url = '/localhost/page2'+web;
```

then it should work.